# Will a 28-inch suitcase exceed the size limitation in Poland's trains?

Tags: trains, poland, warsaw, poznan

I'm to arrive at Warsaw airport October 28. Onwards to Poznan by train. I will stay in Poland for more than four months, almost the whole winter, so I have to take lots of cloths and daily stuff.

I have a 28-inch suitcase about 29 * 52 * 78 cm, which is under airline check-in luggage limits. But basically a train trip doesn't supply check-in luggage service, so I must take care of my suitcase myself. I'm afraid the overhead racks and space under the seats can not take a suitcase of this size.

The PKP website says that oversize luggage should be charged an extra PLN 5.10 fee, but it doesn't specify what is oversize. In China's high speed train I can put large luggage in the shelves at the end of carriage or even in the aisle beside me, but it's my first time to Poland so I don't understand the train there.

Also, I found that there are IC, EIC and TLK trains between Warsaw and Poznan. The speed is similar but TLK has a lower price, so is there anything different among these trains, especially the service and inner facility?

Comment: Having travelled Polish trains, they don't typically make too much of a fuss over luggage size unless it's somewhere in the way. And besides, 5.10 PLN works out to about a US dollar - hardly a big deal in the grand scheme of things, unless you're going to be spending 6 months travelling everywhere by train.

Comment: 29x52x78 doesn't sound like a big suitcase.

Comment: TLK stands more or less for "inexpensive railway lines"

Comment: Do not worry. No one checks luggage sizes in polish trains, ever. Every passanger assumes ticket covers unlimited luggage.

Answer (score 12):

Polish train carriages use a mix of [open](http://d.polskatimes.pl/k/r/1/85/ef/516cb2bc3f23d_p.jpg) and [compartment](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-GV4CRx7C9nc/VcYH87OUvAI/AAAAAAAAHKE/3hRag3aJ6cg/s1600/DSCN3324-2.jpg)-style rolling stock. Generally, the open carriages have both overhead shelves and also shelves at the end of the carriages where you can put large items. The compartments have only overhead shelves, but these should be big enough for your case. In my experience, if you are seen to be struggling getting your case onto them you will also find Poles happy to help lift it into position.

I do not know what counts as oversize luggage, but I would be astounded if your bag were classified that way given some of the luggage I've seen pass without comment on Polish trains.

TLK trains have a lower standard of comfort than IC and EIC - they are generally older, seats are more cramped and they are not quite as clean. However, they are perfectly acceptable for most travellers and there is a first class option that will be more comfortable. [Here are some images of first class and second class (I klasy / II klasy) seats on TLK trains.](http://kolej.darlex.pl/543-tlk)

Comment: Intercity [does specify what oversize is](https://www.intercity.pl/pl/site/dla-pasazera/3052/przewoz-rowerow-rzeczy-i-zwierzat/przewoz-rzeczy.html): Anything that cannot be put on the luggage shelf or under the seat, and that's it.

Comment: `[...] you will also find Poles happy to help lift it into position`  That sounds curiously like the setup to a lightbulb joke.  How many Poles *does* it take to screw a suitcase into light socket, by the way?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Two with bad coordination, and the rest of your travel is kinda dark :(

Answer (score 3):

I've carried normal-size suitcases on Polish trains on several occasions, and never had any problems or had to pay any extra fee.

As Martin says, the TLK trains are older and less comfortable. They are usually also slower, as (on some routes) the EIC/EIP trains use new high-speed lines - but I don't think that includes the Warsawa - Poznan route

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, they don't care. Have it on your laps if you're stressed.
Source - I'm Polish

Comment: Welcome to TSA. Adding a reference may help improve your answer.

Comment: @Newton I guess you mean TSE, for travel.stackexchange.com. TSA here means something else (and they are not known for being kind and welcoming...). :)

Comment: yes exactly, unintentional typo :(